# isAssignableFrom doesn't return true for sub-class

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass

So I want to check to see if a class is assignable to a super class that contains many sub classes, something like this

```
public class A { 
    public A(){ }
}

public class B extends A { 
    public B(){ }
}

public class C extends B {
    public C(){ }
}

public static void main() {
    A a = new C();
    boolean whyAmIFalse = a.getClass().isAssignableFrom(B.class);
}
```

Why does this return false?  Obviously it can be assigned to class B as

```
B b = (B)a
```

does not return an error, so why is this returning false.  Is it not the function it describes itself as?  Is there a function that does accomplish what I want it to me (ie I am that class or a subclass of it)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If what you want to do is test whether or not `a`'s actual type is `B` or a subtype, you've got it backwards: it's

```
 B.class.isAssignableFrom(a.getClass());
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I've been fighting with this for the past like hour.  I feel like an idiot now =).

Answer (score 5):

This is because `getClass()` returns the actual class, not the declared class of a variable -- `a.getClass()` will return the class `C` (C.class), which is the actual class of the object that was assigned to the variable `A a` and you indeed can't assign a `B` to a `C`

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29)

Comment: Is there a way I can say, is this class the class I want or any subclass of it?

Comment: Yes, `isAssignableFrom`.  But I suspect you might mean `B.class.isAssignableFrom(a.getClass())`, not the other way around.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Oh man you nailed it, that is exactly what I wanted.  If you want to post an answer with that comment I'll mark it, I just wrote what I wanted backwards.

Answer (score 0):

Because class B doesn't extend/implement class C, which is what isAssignableFrom() tests. An instance of class B might be an instance of class C, as per your example. To test that, use 'instanceof'.